# How can I check if the scrollbar exists within the table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a table like this that triggers an action which enables the button when user scrolls to the bottom of the table.

```
<div (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
  <table mat-table
         ....
  </table>
</div>
```

In my `ts` file,

```
onScroll(event: any) {
  if (event.target.offsetHeight + event.target.scrollTop >= event.target.scrollHeight) {
    this.dataReviewed = true;
  }
}
```

Now this table can have a single row as well within the table. In such case, scrolling won't work and the button will stay disable. How can I enable the button in case user doesn't need scrolling?

Comment: What's the point of disabling the button to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to manually trigger `onScroll()` when the component loads, but to do that you will have to get a reference to that element

```html
<div #myScrollContainer (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
  <table mat-table
         ....
  </table>
</div>

<button type="button" [disabled]="dataReviewed">My Button</button>
```

Now we get a reference in the controller via `@ViewChild` and then we can manually dispatch a scroll event to that element.

Do note that this needs to happen in the `ngAfterViewChecked` and then after a very small delay to avoid an error about changing the data too soon after it was checked.

```ts
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('myScrollContainer')
  myScrollContainer!: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  dataReviewed = false;

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    //After the view has been checked, we need to wait a little while so we don't interfere with the current cycle
    setTimeout(() => {
      //Next we can manually trigger a scroll event to occur on the element
      this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));
    }, 10);
  }

  onScroll(event: Event) {
    //no need to keep checking once we enable the button
    if (!this.dataReviewed) {
      const tgt = event.target as HTMLElement;
      if (tgt.offsetHeight + tgt.scrollTop >= tgt.scrollHeight) {
        this.dataReviewed = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a working demo that has two containers, one with long content and one with short content: https://stackblitz.com/edit/finitelooper-ng16-89bkmc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Please note that I added proper typing to the variables because that's the entire point of using TypeScript. Please avoid using `any` at all costs! It will save you in the future.

Comment: What you explained is exactly I am trying to achieve. However, `this.onScroll` in `ngOnInit` won't work since it expects an event. How can I pass an event in there inside `ngOnInit`?

Comment: Ah yes, good point!  I missed that. The `$event` that gets passed in there is a `scroll` Event I assume?  Is that when that `div` with a fixed height is scrolled of the entire `window`?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @Kane21 Ok, see my updated answer. I've provided a link to a working demo as well